# Redirect or load a view in MVC?

Tags: model-view-controller, language-agnostic

There are times when the document the user is looking for is not present in our the database, we want to inform them that the document does not exist. We can either redirect them to another page or load another view, which one is appropriate? When to use redirect over view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not return a view with a 404 status code?

Use Redirect if you want to send them to a new part of the site.  Perhaps a search page, or the home page.

Use a Not Found View and a 404 status code if you want to inform them the url they have reached is not valid.  Also this can be good for SEO.  You dont want to be sending a bunch of 302 redirects to Google or it will hit you hard.

Comment: Because I'm not sure if it is the right thing to do. Can you give me some pointers when to use view over redirect?

Comment: Sure.  It depends on the flow of your site.  Do you want the user to stop and take notice that this has happened?  If a user comes from an external link do you want them to always end up on a useful page or a page telling them the link they used was not valid?  In most cases I spit out a not found view with a 404.

Answer (score 1):

@dpp I don't see any major differences, apart from the URL changing. I guess its cleaner if you do a redirect.

If it's not found, then you should issue or load a 404 page. Doing a redirect causes a 302 code, followed by a '200 OK', implying that there IS some content. A 404 flat out says "there is no file".

Something like this would present a 404 page with proper header code:

```
<?php
if ($page_not_found) {
   header('This is not the page you are looking for', true, 404);
   include('your_404_page.php');
   exit();
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain why it is cleaner?